# error while stopping windows service programmatically

Tags: exception, windows-services

I have a windows service. In the OnStart method, I am performing some operation and if one of the operation fails, I want service to stop. In the Catch block I am writing below mentioned code:

```
var srvc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("Scv1", "localhost");
srvc.Stop();
srvc.WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
```

It does the job well but windows shows me a messagebox:

```
---------------------------
Services
---------------------------
The xxx service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I suppress the messagebox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a basic test service in C#, installed it on Windows 7, and then tried to start it.

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

public class MyService : ServiceBase
{
  static void Main()
  {
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run( new MyService() );
  }

  protected override void OnStart( string[] args )
  {
    bool failed = true;
    // Do stuff...
    // Oops, we failed! Time to stop!
    if( failed ) {
      base.Stop();
      return;
    }
    base.OnStart( args );
  }
}
```

When it fails, yes, I do see the message box that you describe. This message box is not part of your service -- the Services window is showing that. If you were to open an administrator command prompt and type the following:

```
net start Scv1
```

Then you would see a text-based error message instead of a message box.

In either case, you are running a program that asks the SCM to start your service. Your service failed to start. That failure is reported back to the program. The program has decided to display an error message to inform the user. That is beyond your control.

Comment: it does the same thing. stops the service. problem is the message box that windows pops up bcz i am stopping it programatically.

Comment: Yes it does the same thing, but it does it correctly! I'm telling you that the way you are doing it is not the proper way for a service to stop itself programatically, and perhaps that is the cause of your message box problem. My services have never thrown up a message box like you describe when I stop them due to a failure during startup. I don't know how ServiceBase works, but in a native service, depending on how you've set the service status, sending a stop command through the SCM wouldn't even work if the service isn't accepting external stop requests.

Comment: i dont understand what you are saying. I changed my code and i am holding the instance of my service in a static variable. Since My service inherits from System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase so when i call Stop, it calls ServiceBase.Stop because it inherits from it. It still shows the message box. What is Native Service?

Comment: @Asdfg: "What is Native Service?" -> an unmanaged service, I presume. I.e. native as opposed to managed code.

Comment: Your error is just the services window reporting that your service failed to start; see the edits to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually check the event handler. It will intimate you the mistake you have done in the configuration file. Some syntax error in the configuration file will be the reason for this kind of message box.